# google-app-engine: Sending email from form data?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

How do I generate a response and email for some form data. I tried something like:

```
import webapp2
from google.appengine.api import mail

MAIN_PAGE_HTML = """\
<html>
  <body>
   <h1>response to GET</h1>
  </body>
</html>
"""

class My_Email_Class(webapp2.RequestHandler):
      def get(self):
          user_address = self.request.get("email")
          user_name = self.request.get("name")

          if not mail.is_email_valid(user_address):
              pass

          message = mail.EmailMessage()
          message.sender = 'xyz@xyz.com'
          message.to = 'abcd@abcd.com'
          message.subject = "Website:" + str(user_name + user_email)
          message.body = """\
Hi
"""
          message.send()

          self.response.write(MAIN_PAGE_HTML)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/mail-me.py', My_Email_Class),], debug=True)
```

I'm mapping the script via `app.yaml` and the script line:

```
- url: /mail-me.py.*
  script: mail-me.py
```

I'm invoking it using: `dev_appserver.py ~root/whatever/`
and browsing: `localhost:8080`

I'm seeing no errors but there's no response page either in the browser

---

Also tried (`app.yaml`):

```
application: hello
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: no

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: main.py
```

`main.py`

```
import os
import webapp2
class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    print 'Content-Type: text/plain'
    print ''
    print 'Hello, world!'

application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([(r'/', MainHandler)], debug=True)
```

`INFO     2015-11-10 06:29:51,805 module.py:794] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out: poor documentation!
This works:

```
import os
import webapp2

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    print 'Content-Type: text/plain'
    print ''
    print 'Hello, world!'

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([(r'/', MainHandler),], debug=True)


application: hello
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: no

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: main.app
```

> script: main.**app**
>
> **app** = webapp2.WSGIApplication([(r'/', MainHandler),], debug=True)

**app** has to match, so you could expand that to **application** if you like or **appxxx**. **py** doesn't work though!

Comment: [A script: directive can contain either a file path ending in .py (meaning that the script uses CGI)](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig?hl=en#Python_app_yaml_Script_handlers) Your initial attempt had a WSGI app called app but you were adding it as if it were a CGI script.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try browsing to `localhost:8080/mail-me.py`?  That is what your routing uses to call your `get()` method.

You don't need to include `.py` in your URL.  Use `('/mail-me', My_Email_Class)` instead, and then browse to `localhost:8080/mail-me`.

Comment: made those changes, still blank, `INFO     2015-11-10 02:28:58,793 module.py:794] default: "GET /mail-me HTTP/1.1" 200 -` checking some more..